# How to run R script containing interactive user options from a batch file

Tags: r, batch-file, cmd, rstudio

I have written an interactive R Script which gives the user certain options using which the rest of the execution takes place. These inputs have to be optional as required by the user. One other requirement from the user was that he did not want to manually select the entire script in RStudio just to execute it. I tried to create a `BAT` file for this execution. However, the program does not execute. Below is an example user interactive script.

```
FYI_Splitter <- winDialog(type = "yesno","Do you want to remove FYI from base file?

Yes = Remove FYI
No = Do Not Remove FYI")
```

Below is what I am using to execute the `BAT` file.

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "<Path_of_file>\Test_Program.R"
```

I came to know that batch file execution does not support interactive sessions. Is there any way to make interactive sessions in R execute without selecting the entire code in RStudio? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
echo source("<Path_of_file>\Test_Program.R") | R.exe --ess --vanilla
```

The interactive() command in R then returns TRUE for me.

Comment: Thanks @Slimemold. I will give this a try and keep you informed if this works. Just one question. Is `--vanilla` required in the code?

Comment: If I leave it out I get an error telling me to choose between --vanilla, --save and --no-save.

Comment: Are you adding the exact same code in the BAT file? Is there anything else I should be adding? Because it does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: I only run this single line. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Well, I am not an expert with BAT files. When I place the line you provided, change the path of file correctly, and run it, nothing happens. I do see some message written but not able to see it as it closes instantly. I even tried adding the full path to `R.exe` in your line but it too did not work.

Comment: Me neither... 
I have the same problem and I am currently trying to solve it but had no success so far.
Does interactive() return TRUE for you too at least?

Comment: Yes, it does return TRUE to me.